# Login application using Spring MVC not working properly

Tags: java, xml, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Hi I have created a login application using Spring MVC however it seems not working properly. The issue is with the logic which i have used in my Authenticate class for returning username and password from hibernate. I am taking empty list from authenticate class if it doesn't retains any username or password and it is not validating the login properly and login is happening even for wrong username and password.

below is my controller:

```
package com.lnt.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.lnt.services.AuthenticateServices;

@Controller 
@RequestMapping("/Login.spring")
public class LoginController {

    //@Autowired
     AuthenticateServices authenticateService = new AuthenticateServices();

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView processCredentials(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)

    {
        String userName =req.getParameter("userName") ;
        String password = req.getParameter("password");
        System.out.println("into login controller");
        System.out.println(userName);
        System.out.println(password);
        String message = "Invalid credentials";
        List<String> userdetails = new ArrayList<String>();
        userdetails = authenticateService.verifyUserNameAndPassword(userName, password);
        //System.out.println(userdetails.get(0)+ "index0");
        if((userdetails)!=null)
            {
            message = "welcome" + userName ;

        }
        return new ModelAndView("results", "message", message) ;
    }
```

Here is my JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="Login.htm" method = "post">
<input type = "text" name = "userName" id = "userName">
<input type = "password" name = "password" id = "password">
<input type = "submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my authenticate service class :

```
package com.lnt.services;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.SQLQuery;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

//import org.apache.catalina.Session;



public class AuthenticateServices {

    //private org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate HibernateTemplate ;

    public AuthenticateServices() {

    }

    /*public AuthenticateServices(
            org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate) {
        super();
        HibernateTemplate = hibernateTemplate;
    }*/

    public List<String> verifyUserNameAndPassword(String userName, String Password)
    {
        //Session session = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory().openSession() ;
        //ser = null ;
        System.out.println("into checking the verifyingusername and status");
        List<String> userobjs = null ; 
        //boolean userstatus = false;
        try
        {

        Session session = null ;
        session = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory().openSession(); 
        Transaction tx = null;
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        //List<User> userobjs = HibernateTemplate.find("from user where. u.Username=? and u.password=?",userName,Password);
            StringBuilder searchQuery = new StringBuilder();
            searchQuery.append("Select loginid, password from login_info where loginid ='" + userName + "' and password = '" + Password + "'");
        //System.out.println(userobjs + "userobjects");
            tx.commit();
            SQLQuery Sqlquery = session.createSQLQuery(searchQuery.toString());
            userobjs = Sqlquery.list();
            System.out.println("userlist" + userobjs);
            System.out.println("query used" + Sqlquery);
            session.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        if (userobjs!=null)
        {
        return userobjs ;
        }

        else
        {
            return null;
        }
        }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you are doing wrong, but it seems that are you sort of reinventing the wheel here... What you are trying to do is totally covered by Spring Security. Check out [this](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/16/jdbc-user-service-based-spring-security-example/) tutorial